# Using Bing maps to track multiple drivers

Tags: asp.net, bing-maps, tracking

i am using bing maps with asp .net. i want to track multiple users ( drivers ) . i found a demo on how to track a user in bing website but i didn't figure out how to track specific user with specific id. here is the code to track user

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var map, watchId, userPin;

    function GetMap()
    {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: ‘Your Bing Maps Key’
        });
    }

    function StartTracking() {
        //Add a pushpin to show the user's location.
        userPin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(map.getCenter(), { visible: false });
        map.entities.push(gpsPin);

        //Watch the users location.
        watchId = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(UsersLocationUpdated);
    }

    function UsersLocationUpdated(position) {
        var loc = new Microsoft.Maps.Location(
                    position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude);

        //Update the user pushpin.
        userPin.setLocation(loc);
        userPin.setOptions({ visible: true });

        //Center the map on the user's location.
        map.setView({ center: loc });
    }

    function StopTracking() {
        // Cancel the geolocation updates.
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(watchId);

        //Remove the user pushpin.
        map.entities.clear();
    }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div><br/>
    <input type="button" value="Start Continuous Tracking" onclick="StartTracking()" />
    <input type="button" value="Stop Continuous Tracking" onclick="StopTracking()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided will show the user where they are on the map. If you want to see the location of multiple drivers on a map, you will need to capture the location of each driver from a device and get that data into a backend service, then have that backend service send the data to the frontend map canvas (i.e. Bing Maps). There are a lot of different ways to do this.

First you need to know how you are going to capture the drivers location. Two common methods:

1. A mobile app that uses the native geolocation APIs in the background and sends updates to the backend service.
2. A dedicated IoT device that is either connected to the vehicle or in the vehicle.

A really quick way to do this is to leverage Azure IoT hub for the backend service and IoT central for the frontend. Here is a reference architecture: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/solution-ideas/articles/real-time-asset-tracking-mgmt-iot-central

Bing maps has an open-source project that leverages mobile devices and displays the data on a map: https://github.com/Microsoft/Bing-Maps-Fleet-Tracker

Comment: thanks alot for the information .. i have another question please . is there a way to capture location if driver uses website in mobile browser

Comment: Yes, there is the geolocation API in browsers you can use. Similar to apps, the driver still has to consent to sharing their location. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation_API/Using_the_Geolocation_API